# How can I read a file content multiple times in C

Tags: c, file, read-write, fgetc

I am trying to do a simple todo list in C, but the read option only shows the correct info on the first run. If I add a new item, then I need to close and open the program again to show the updated list.

The add option is working fine and the delete option is not implemented yet.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    int opt = 1;
    char task[50];
    char add[50];
    char read;
    FILE *p, *q;

    printf("\n===To-do List Simple Application===\n");
    printf("Choose an Option:\n");
    do {
        printf("1- Show List\n");
        printf("2- Add an item\n");
        printf("3- Delete an item\n");
        printf("0- Exit\n");
        scanf("%d" ,&opt);
        switch(opt){
        case 1:
            q = fopen("list.txt", "r");
            printf("\n\n==================\n");
            read = fgetc(q);
            while (read != EOF){
                printf("%c" ,read);
                read = fgetc(q);
            }
            printf("%s \n", task);
            printf("\n==================\n\n");
            break;

        case 2:
            p = fopen("list.txt", "a");
            printf("\n\n==================\n");
            printf("Inform the item to be added:\n");
            scanf("%s" ,add);
            fprintf(p, "\n%s",add);
            printf("\n==================\n\n");
            break;

        case 3:
            printf("\n\n==================\n");
            printf("delete\n");
            printf("\n==================\n\n");
            break;

        case 0: 
            printf("\n\n==================\n");
            printf("exit\n");
            printf("\n==================\n\n");
            break;
        }   
    }while (opt!=0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can use `fseek()` to go back to the beginning of the file and read it again.

Comment: You need to close the file or call `fflush()` after adding to the file, to flush the output buffer.

Comment: Note also that `fgetc()` returns `int`, not `char`, because `EOF` is a value that can not be represented in a `char` value.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET)` or `rewind(file)` to start reading/writing from/to the beginning of the file again.

Note that if you have the file open in append mode, these will essentially do nothing; all writes will still be forced to the end of the file.

However, these won't fix your code. You need to close the file after you're done writing or reading to/from it.

Along with that, you're using `task` when it's uninitialized. Initialize it or check if it's initialized before you start using it to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're not closing the file after writing to it. This will flush the output buffer. The file is closed automatically when the program exits, that's why reopening the program solves the problem.

You should also close the file at the end of the reading case, since you reopen it each time you read, rather than reusing the existing open stream.

Printing `task` causes undefined behavior, since you never initialized `task`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    int opt = 1;
    char task[50];
    char add[50];
    char read;
    FILE *p, *q;

    printf("\n===To-do List Simple Application===\n");
    printf("Choose an Option:\n");
    do {
        printf("1- Show List\n");
        printf("2- Add an item\n");
        printf("3- Delete an item\n");
        printf("0- Exit\n");
        scanf("%d" ,&opt);
        switch(opt){
        case 1:
            q = fopen("list.txt", "r");
            printf("\n\n==================\n");
            read = fgetc(q);
            while (read != EOF){
                printf("%c" ,read);
                read = fgetc(q);
            }
            fclose(q);
            // printf("%s \n", task);
            printf("\n==================\n\n");
            break;

        case 2:
            p = fopen("list.txt", "a");
            printf("\n\n==================\n");
            printf("Inform the item to be added:\n");
            scanf("%s" ,add);
            fprintf(p, "\n%s",add);
            fclose(p);
            printf("\n==================\n\n");
            break;

        case 3:
            printf("\n\n==================\n");
            printf("delete\n");
            printf("\n==================\n\n");
            break;

        case 0: 
            printf("\n\n==================\n");
            printf("exit\n");
            printf("\n==================\n\n");
            break;
        }   
    }while (opt!=0);
    return 0;
}
```